# Inequalities with multiple conditions help

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If I have 3 variables, $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ which can all take values between plus/minus infinity, what values of $x_1$ satisfy all conditions:

$x_2 > x_1 >x_3$

$x_2>0$

$x_3<0$

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Which number you tried to take?

Comment: Does $x_1$ have to satisfy all inequalities, whatever the values of $x_2,x_3$ are?

Comment: @Dr.Mathva  To clarify in words.....I'm looking for all values of $x_1$ such that it must be less than $x_2$ and greater than $x_3$,   where $x_2 >0$ and $x_3 < 0$

Comment: Well, since $x_2 >0$ and $x_3 <0$, the interval $[x_3, x_2]$ is nonempty since it includes the value $0$.  So the answer is simply the first condition, i.e. the values of $x_1$ which satisfy all three conditions are given by all $x_1$ with $x_2 > x_1 >x_3$.